# How to create a rainbow in my house?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, home-experiment

If I want to create a rainbow in my house, how should I go about it?

Comment: Search term: thin-film interference

Comment: [Make a permanent rainbow](https://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/light/permanent_rainbows/permanent_rainbows.html)

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes, but the colors are not those of rainbows. I once doctored this photo: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Film_of_soap_interference_3_RGB.jpg

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, consider upvoting or accepting helpful answers, or writing your own answer to your question. These things make your question more useful to future readers.

Comment: Make sure your homeowners' policy is up to date, and covers water damage.

Comment: You can use a [water prism](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=53122762#53122762)

Answer (score 1):

You will not see colors under a yellow light; you can at best only see colors that are in the illuminating light.

The oil needs to be able to spread out into a very thin layer on water.  Some oils won't do that.  You may need to experiment with your available oils.

Illumination needs to be diffuse.  Shine a white light onto a white wall, and let the scattered light from the wall reflect off the oil film.

The colors depend on the thickness of the oil layer.  Usually the oil will get thinner and thinner until it is one molecule thick, and where it's that thin the color is likely to be grey instead of a pure color.

Comment: Sunlight is effectively white light.  By "illuminating light" I mean whatever light you use to illuminate the oil film.

Comment: Can you add a photo and details of your experiment, to your question?

Comment: I would think that the illumination should approximate a point source.